# Solution of under determinant system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, regression

What is the mathematical technique to solve homogeneous under determined system of eqns. Ax=0, while minimizing the vector x in the sense of L1 norm?

Comment: Did you mean "under-determined" as in when the number of equations is less than the number of unknowns?

Comment: Oh yes I am sorry for this typo. I guess that LASSO algorithm solves for this problem in case of the r.h.s is non zero. but while zero r.h.s I do not know how to get non trivial solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solving $Ax=0$ means finding the basis of null space of $A$.

One way of finding the basis of null space is to compute SVD of A: $$A = U\Sigma V^*$$

The right-singular vectors ($V$) corresponding to vanishing singular values ($\Sigma$) of $A$ span the null space of $A$. Now, given the whole basis of null space, find the columns which has minimum sum and that is your solution.

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition#Range,_null_space_and_rank